# Update multiple rows with different values at once using a where statement

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

So i'm facing the following problem. I'm using python to do some calculations. The outcome of these calculations is a array of unique values. Now I want to add these values to a PostgreSQL table without using a loop. A simple example:

Outcome of the calculations in Python:

```
[1.2, 2.4, 3.6, 4.8]
```

PostgreSQL table:

```
example_table

id | date         | values
-------------------------
 1 | 2016-11-01   | 
 2 | 2016-11-01   | 
 3 | 2016-11-01   | 
 4 | 2016-11-01   | 
 5 | 2017-11-01   | 
 6 | 2017-11-01   |
```

Wat I want to achieve is to add the above values to the 'values' column in the table, **where the date is '2016-11-01'**. The length of the array is always the same as the selected table. Example of the result:

```
example_table

id | date         | values
-------------------------
 1 | 2016-11-01   | 1.2
 2 | 2016-11-01   | 2.4
 3 | 2016-11-01   | 3.6
 4 | 2016-11-01   | 4.8
 5 | 2017-11-01   | 
 6 | 2017-11-01   |
```

This should also work in this scenario;
python array:

```
[1.2, 2,4]
```

and then add the above values to the 'values' column in the table, **where the date is '2017-11-01'**.
Result:

```
example_table

id | date         | values
-------------------------
 1 | 2016-11-01   | 
 2 | 2016-11-01   | 
 3 | 2016-11-01   | 
 4 | 2016-11-01   | 
 5 | 2017-11-01   | 1.2
 6 | 2017-11-01   | 2.4
```

What I've tried so far is:

```
INSERT INTO example_table (values) VALUES ('1.2'), ('2.4'), ('3.6'), ('4.8')
```

Which works, but I cannot add a WHERE statement as INSERT INTO does not support this. 
When using UPDATE I either manage to add the whole array to each row, or add the first value to each row, but not the array of values to each row. I cannot link the values to an ID, but the order of the values is always the same as the order of the selected rows.

It seems like a fairly simple and basic operation, but I do not get it to work properly. How do I add this array of values to a column at once using a WHERE statement? I'm sending the SQL requests via Python.

Comment: Does `id` always reflect the position of the value in the array?

Comment: Have you tried moving the data (id and date) from SQL to python, joining it there and then inserting it as a new table in SQL?

Comment: Could indeed be a solution, but I need to add just the values to the existing table without changing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a where clause with an Insert.

To get your desired results you need to use Update. A a-horse states its important to know if your array will keep the order that you are suggesting in your example. If so you could loop through it and perform an update. Something like:

```
i=1; 
for a in [1.2, 2.4, 3.6, 4.8]:
    UPDATE example_table set values = a where id = i ;
    i += 1;
```

(excuse my Python)

Comment: This wil work only when the values are in the same order of the ID, but this is not always the case, for example when I want to add [1.2, 2.4] WHERE date = '2017-11-01'

Comment: your data is inconsistent between environments. Its probably better to process this all in Python then transfer to Postgres.